# MySQL connection and security

Tags: mysql, security, encryption

I was wondering if someone could tell me if there is any potential security breeches that could occur by connecting to a MySQL database that does not reside at 'localhost' i.e. via IP address?

Comment: maybe move this question to severfault.com?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, breaches do occur by not protecting the connection to your database.   This is a network secuirty question more so than an Application secuirty question.  Thus this answer is entirely dependent on your network topography.

If a segment of your network maybe accessible by an attacker, then you must protect yourself with cryptography.  For instance you have a malicious individual who has compromised a machine on your network, then they can conduct an [ARP Spoofing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARP_spoofing) attack to "Sniff" or even MITM devices on a switched network.  This could be used to see all data that flows in and out of your database,  or modify the database's response to a specific query (like a login!).  If the network connection to your database is a single rj45 twisted connection to your httpd server all residing inside a locked cabinet,  then you don't have to worry about a hacker sniffing this.   But if your httpd is on a wifi network and then connecting to a database in China,  then you might want to think about encryption.

You should connect to your MySQL database using [MySQL's built-in SSL ability](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/secure-basics.html).  This insures that all data transferred is highly protected.   You should create self-signed x509 certificates and  hard code them.  This is free,  and you don't need a CA like Verisign for this.    If there is a certificate exception then there is a MITM and thus this stops you from spilling the password.

Another option is a [VPN](http://openvpn.net/), and this is better suited if you have multiple daemons that require secure point to point connections.

Comment: wow... I have really little experience in servers and such... I will be renting a dedicated server from heartinternet for my latest project. the 99% of the site will reside there, the small percent ( 1 page ) will be on a different server ( a reseller account ) which will be used only to display a users profile page ( the profile url is a wildcard subdomain which the domain is shorter than the previous - only reason why i asked ).

Comment: Would it be wise to keep both domains on the dedicated server?

Comment: For a simplicity and secuirty I would host the reseller page on the same server.  If you need to share user account information between servers I would look into oAuth/OpenID or perhaps a custom SOAP service,  depending on your needs.

Comment: Also well working connection persistence if possible otherwise your application will suffer a bit if you do a lot of connections. It could kill down to 10 connections per sec from a single fast-cgi server. SQL over the network is not that easy part, and using SQL locally and profiling the DB nicely is really better working in some cases.

Answer (score 2):

It's usually the other way round that the bigger problem lies, vulnerabilities in the MySQL server being exploited by untrustworthy clients.

However, yes, there have also been client vulnerabilities in the past ([eg.](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2002-1376)) that would allow an untrustworthy server to attack the client.

Naturally you should keep your MySQL client libraries up to date to avoid such possibilities, as well as updating the server.

If your connection to the server is going over the internet (rather than a private network), you should consider running it over an encrypted link (either MySQL's own SSL scheme or using a tunnel). Otherwise any man-in-the-middle could fiddle with the data going in and out of the database, and if there are client or server vulnerabilities those could also be targeted.

Comment: In this scenario a firewall/user account settings is better suited than a tunnel.  +1 Rogue clients is a valid concern when having a remote database.

Answer (score 0):

If the servers are in the same rack, you can use dedicated high-speed MySQL cable, or use switch VLAN isolation, and protect the database OS. In cloud with the virtual cloud network you can connect it the way that arp spoof is not possible, and for the geo-ip replication, you can use user/password and firewall, and then measure the performance, and then setup a tunnel and measure performance again, if it's not bad, it might be worth against unknown threats or just useful in using spare cpu cycles.

Simply SQL servers has to be on isolated network, and not into the public, as rule of thumb, you never publish open database connection to anyone, and keep it with seriously good firewall filtering on separate subnet made for handling sensitive data with very good arp spoofing protection, otherwise it's crackable and the major parts of the system can be compromised using several techniques, and it's very nice and sometimes very easy to handle it this way, e.g. to control, monitor and policy the MySQL traffic with hardware layer - and it really does the job and makes a real difference.

Optionally you can keep it on encrypted hard-drive in physically safe place along with the switch, so upon breaking the power its switched off, and the private key erased, hence both layer-1 and layer-2 are secured.

On the switch to use the static ARP table plus the filtering for the static entries versus the port is very easy to do because it's also physical layer - the port number.